# how to check content of request_uri

Tags: php, url

hello i would like to know how to avoid double postings in a request_uri.

as an example:

```
http://www.example.com/foo/foo/...
```

should only be:

```
http://www.example.com/foo/...
```

for example i would like to create a check that i need for a header-function that needs to be checked before it headers. it should not header if the url-string contains double postings. so the check would be something like:

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$urlArray = explode('/', $url);
$urlArrayUnique = array_unique($urlArray);
$urlUnique = implode('/', $urlArrayUnique);

if (isset($_SESSION['a'])){
    $var = $_SESSION['a'];
    if($url !== $urlUnique){
        header ('Location:'.$host.'/'.$var.'/'.$basename);
        exit;
    }
}
```

if there is someone who could help me out i really would appreciate.

thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, use **explode** and get unique and **implode** it into URL....

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$urlArray = explode('/', $url);

$urlArrayUnique = array_unique($urlArray);

$urlUnique = implode('/', $urlArrayUnique);
```

You can get dulicate values in $urlArray too...

Comment: hello and thanks for answering this question. something seems to be wrong. when using this and if($url !== $urlUnique){
  header ('Location:'.$host.'/'.$var.'/'.$basename);
  exit;
 } ->makes the complete url repeating again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this below code to suit as per your need:

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$urlArray = explode('/', $url);
$lai = max(array_keys($urlArray));//here we get the max array index    
if($urlArray[$lai-1] != $urlArray[$lai])header('Location:'.$host.'/'.$var.'/'.$basename);
```